# Convert text to xml using xslt without providing input file name

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want my text file to convert to xml file using xslt without giving the input file name.I worked on the below code but it takes the file name.Without giving file name how to transform some text to xml as in the below Output.xml.Can someone please help me out here.

**Input.txt:**

```
12/34/56/78/9/123/
```

**Transform.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result- 
 prefixes="xs fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="pathToFile" select="'file:///c:/Input.txt'" />
<xsl:param name="filename" select="'file:///c:/Output.xml'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToFile)">

       <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" method="xml">
         <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($pathToFile)" />
         <xsl:copy>       
           <File>
              <xsl:value-of select="$csv" />
           </File>
         </xsl:copy> 
      </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text>Cannot locate : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of 
         select="$pathToFile" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <File>1/23/456/7/8/14/9/</File>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which XSLT processor you use, how you call it (command line, API, inside of an IDE) and in what way you expect a computer program like an XSLT stylesheet to process some input file without providing the input file name.

In general in XSLT 2 and later you can, instead of providing an XML input document where processing starts with a template matching it, start processing with a named template. In XSLT 2 you will have to choose one (e.g. `<xsl:template match="main">...</xsl:template>`) or in XSLT 3 you can name it `<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">...</xsl:template>`. You will then have to use processor or IDE specific means of setting up the transformation to use that template.

I don't understand how you expect to process a text input file without providing its file name.